# Claws Mail on Ubuntu - Can't customise keyboard shortcuts on the fly

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, claws-mail

In Claws Mail 3.11.1 on Ubuntu 14.04/ Unity desktop, 'Enable customisable keyboard shortcuts' is checked.
But when a menu item is higlighted, nothing happens when I press keys (unless the key combo is assigned in System Settings).
Can anyone else reproduce this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me, Claws Mail 3.9.3 in XFCE. After enabling the checkbox, opening a menu and highlighting a menu item with the mouse and *then* pressing a keyboard button (tried letters, function keys, plus Shift Ctrl Alt - any 1 or all 3) assigns that letter combo as the new shortcut "on-the-fly."

Here's a screenshot of the options, and the kind of buried but very helpful text in the "Choose preset keyboard shortcuts" popup.

[image]

Is that not what yours is doing? I'm not using Unity so can't compare with it directly, do you think it's "stealing" the keypresses? Do any of the keyboard shortcuts work when no menus are open?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-E is assigned to 'gedit' in System Settings and if I try to assign this combo on-the-fly to a menu item in Claws, gedit is launched. So maybe Unity is stealing this keypress. As to shortcuts already defined in menurc, they do work.

Comment: Probably, so you can't have overlapping shortcut keys it looks like. What about every other key or key combination, do any of them work?

Comment: I haven't found a working one so far.